# ANTLR4 grammar which accepts list of optional and required arguments in any order

Tags: antlr, antlr4

How can I write an ANTLR rule that accepts a mixture of optional and required arguments in any order?

For example, a valid query could look like `function(a = 5, c = "foo", b = 21)` or `function(b = 4, c = 5)` where a is optional but c and b are required. The only valid arguments are a, b and c.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not something you would define in your grammar. The grammar would just accept `function(a = 5, c = "foo", b = 21)` and `function(a = 5, c = "foo", i = 21)`. After parsing the input, you would reject the latter example in a traversal of the parse tree.

For example, take the BNF specification of a [Java assignment statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html):

```
Expression: 
    Expression1 [AssignmentOperator Expression1]
```

where `Expression1` might very well be the variable `Q` which is defined as follows:

```
final int Q = 42;
```

In other words: the statement `Q = 123;` would be illegal since it was already defined `final`. Such semantic checks are not defined in the grammar but handled at a later stage.